# How to set Custom data validation in Google Sheets (A really simple step-by-step guide needed)

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, data-validation

I'm trying to figure out how to create custom data validation in Google Sheets what are the steps I need to follow to achieve this?

For example if I wanted the following validation:

```
// Set the data validation for cell A1 to require a value from B1:B10.
var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('A1');
var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getRange('B1:B10');
var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(range).build();
cell.setDataValidation(rule);
```

I have tried the following:

1. Tools > Script Editor ...
2. Paste the code inside a function, e.g. `validate()`
3. pase the function in the cell I want to receive the validation, `=validate()`, but I received the following error "You do not have permission to call setDataValidation"

And the following:

1. Tools > Script Editor ...
2. Paste the code directly in the editor

Comment: I'm just using the code provided as an example, it's not the actual validation I want to use.

Answer (score 1):

## Overview

From [Extend Google Docs, Sheets, and Forms with Apps Script - Docs editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/2942256?hl=en)

> If you’d like to learn Apps Script but you’re new to programming,
> [Codecademy offers a great online JavaScript course for beginners](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript-combined).
> (Note that this course was not developed by and is not associated with
> Google.) Once you feel like you have a handle on JavaScript, try
> either of these Apps Script quickstart tutorials: [Macros, menus, and
> custom functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/macros) or [Managing form responses](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/forms).

## Broad steps

1. Design the automated procedure (similar to a macro) aka script.
2. Create a Google Apps Script project. A [bound script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/bound) is the easiest way for custom validations for Google spreadsheets.
3. Create the main script.
4. Set the trigger method (optional):

   1. [Events object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).
   2. [Installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).
   3. [Custom menu](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus).
5. Execute the script. Repeat as it be necessary.

Note: The script could be called from the Script editor.

## References

[Docs editor Help](http://support.google.com/docs)
[Google Apps Script - Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/)
[Data validation - Extending Google Sheets - Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets#data_validation)